How to get the usage time of an app in kotlin
I'm working on a project that needs to get application usage duration from other apps installed in an Android device. The problem is that using the tools available in Android SDK don't work as expected, the provided time is basically always wrong and with a significant margin of error.
I tried to use UsageStatsManager with the QueryUsageStats (the most simple form) and also tried getting the timestamps of user interactions in Android to try getting a more accurate value, but for some apps it works for another it's a complete failure. On my researches, I find out that this is a long-time problem and don't seems doesn't seem simple to fix, there is a new class (AppUsageStatistics) that seems to work better, but it requires a higher API level, that if it's possible, I would rather not use.
I also tried an app called AppBlocker, it works in older devices and still tracks with good accuracy, so I think that is a way to make it work well.

If real-time usage stats is required, try running it as a foreground service. Or if it's ok, access the usage stats only when the user is actively interacting with your app. If your app attempts to gather UsageStatsManager data while in the background, it may fail or receive outdated information. Also make sure your app isn't restricted by battery optimization settings
